# ES6 Object Literal Syntax for Methods

Tags: methods, ecmascript-6, object-literal

I'm looking at this [this page](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-shorthand) about various shorthand syntaxes in ES6 for declaring methods inside of objects.

I'm not understanding the differences between these two forms:

```
var foo = {
    a() {},
    b() {}
};
```

and

```
var foo = {
    x: (y) => y
};
```

---

The article seems to make a clear distinction between these two formats, but doesn't the first one really just become the second? If we wanted to include parameters, we'd just do `a(y) {}` in the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but doesn't the first one really just become the second?

No. The method syntax is more equivalent to using a **function expression**:

```
var foo = {
  a: function() {},
};
```

If you'd assign an **arrow function** then you won't be able to access the object via `this`.

And of course an *empty function* (`function() {}`) is not the same as the *identity function* (`function(x) { return x; }`).

---

See also

- [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/218196)
- [Methods in ES6 objects: using arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31095710/218196)

Comment: Actually, it is fully equivalent because it's just a shortcut syntax.