# Object.defineProperty duplicates property values

Tags: javascript, this, getter-setter

I was experimenting with some bits of code below and everything seems to be working as expected. The goal was to bind `a.val` to `b.val` such that when `a.val` changed, `b.val` would also change automatically.

```
// instantiate 
var a = {}
var b = {}

// set value
a.val = 10

// check values
console.log("A.val is:", a.val) // 10
console.log("B.val is:", b.val) // undefined

// bind values
Object.defineProperties(a, {
  val: {
    configurable: true, // can be changed or deleted
    enumerable: true,   // can be iterated over
    get: ()=> this.val,
    set: (value)=> {
        this.val = value
        b.val = value
        return value
    }
  }
})

// reset value
a.val = 20

// check values
console.log("A.val is:", a.val) // 20
console.log("B.val is:", b.val) // 20
```

So I wanted to move forward with this concept and abstract the `Object.defineProperties` part into a function. I thought I could make a for loop and loop through the properties of one object, call `Object.defineProperty`. But I ran into some issues:

```
function getSet(props){
  for(var key in props){
    Object.defineProperty(props, key, {
      configurable: true, // can be changed or deleted
      enumerable: true,   // can be iterated over
      get: ()=> this[key],
      set: (value)=> {
          this[key] = value
          return value
      }
    })
  }

  return props
}

var a = getSet({name: 'the letter a', age: 12})

a.name // undefined
a.name = 'the letter a'
a.age // 'the letter a'
```

Essentially I have inadvertently bound the two properties of the object I was passing to the `getSet` function. Furthermore I have erased their initial values.

My question is, why does that happen, and how do I get closer to my goal, of binding the properties of one object to another.

Through testing several other possible solutions I ran into a `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error: I presume when referencing `this` in the getter or setter, the act of getting the value from the object I am trying to define properties on triggers a call to the getter, and loops indefinitely. Not entirely sure when/why this happens.

Comment: `this` does not refer to what you think it does.  In your `getSet` function `this` refers to the window.

Comment: @Tibrogargan: You're right. although. That doesn't entirely solve my problem. I implemented the same thing with a `var copy = Object.assign({}, props)`, and replaced `this` with `copy`. The properties remained bound. If I change `age` it changes `name` and visa versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code doesn't really work. The two major flaws are

- you [cannot use arrow functions with `this` in an object literal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31095710/1048572). The `this` value will be the module object (in node) or global object (`window` in browsers), not the current object.

  - If it had worked as you expected and referenced the receiver of the current access (which also happened when you experimented with a proper method), you would read the value of `a.val` from `a.val` and write the value for `a.val` to `a.val`, creating the infinite recursion you experienced. You need to use something else for the actual storage - in your case, the `b` object is the proper solution.
  - In the browser, assigning to the `name` property of the global object will coerce everything to a string
- in your loop, there's only a [single `key` variable that the getter/setter functions close over](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/1048572). So all of them will use the value in the same place on the store.

To fix this, use

```
function getSet(proxy, store) {
  for (const key in store) {
//     ^^^^^ block scope
    Object.defineProperty(props, key, {
      configurable: true,
      enumerable: true,
      get: () => { return store[key]; },
//                        ^^^^^
      set: (value) => { store[key] = value; }
//                      ^^^^^
    });
  }
  return proxy;
}
```