# React problems with "this" using createReactClass

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const SearchBar = createReactClass({
  getInitialState: () => {
    return { term: '' };
  },
  render: () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          onChange={event => this.setState({ term: event.target.value })}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

This gives me an error: "Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined"
What did I do wrong?

I'm trying to use react in a more functional way. 
Is there any other way to this by the way?
Preferably without using the keyword "this"?

Comment: Arrow functions *close over* `this` rather than having it defined by how they're called. They're not appropriate for use on prototypes. See also the related ES2015 class question and its answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095710/methods-in-es6-objects-using-arrow-functions Make those traditional functions (`render: function() {`) or methods (`render() {`) and it'll work. *(There's no effective difference between a property defined with a traditional function and a method if the method doesn't use `super`. There is if it does.)*

Comment: Instead of render: () => use render: function() which will retain this context. I wouldnt bother with createClass which is older syntax. Definitely not functional either way, just different syntax.

Comment: Thank you T.J.Crowder it's working.
I feel kinda stupid now hahhaha

@jens Is it older syntax? It's very active if you look at it. 1 milion downloads weekly for the create-react-class package

And i've seen some people talking about the advantages and disadvantages like:
https://toddmotto.com/react-create-class-versus-component/
Do you think it's outdated?

Either way, do you think there is any way that I can code in React avoiding the "this" keyword?

Comment: You can use pure components to avoid ‘this’. I don’t think it’s worth tring to avoid ‘this’ conpletely. That article you posted is over 2 years old, so yes outdated.