# Lexical this and objects

Tags: this, javascript-objects

How can i extract the inner id? I know that it's possible to change the fat arrow function to standart function or instead of `this.id` to use `obj.id`.
But is there any other way to get the inner id while using the fat arrow function?

```
var obj = {
  id: 1,
  cool: () => {
    console.log( this.id );
  }
};
var id = 2;
obj.cool(); // 2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Methods in ES6 objects: using arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095710/methods-in-es6-objects-using-arrow-functions)

Answer (score 0):

Arrow function does not create a new scope and uses parent constructor's scope. in this case parent is Windows constructor Function so `this` refers to window and there is no way except the ones you listed

```
var obj = {
  id: 1,
  cool() {
    console.log( this.id );
  }
};
```

Comment: That is not the proper syntax. It would need to be `obj.cool.call(obj)`. 
But even like that its not working.

Comment: arrow function does not create a new scope and uses parent constructor's scope. in this case parent is Windows constructor Function so this refers to window and I guess there is no way except the ones you listed