# The value of 'this' in an arrow function invoked form another function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, this

I have two objects

```
var dog1 = {
    sound: "bark1!",
    bark: () => {
        console.log(this)
        console.log(this.sound);
    }
}
```

and

```
var dog2 = {
    sound: "bark2!",
    bark: function() {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.sound);
        dog1.bark();
    }
}
```

Now I know that if I call `dog1.bark()` I'll have the value of `this` to be equal to `Window` object since the value of `this` for an arrow function is dependent on the lexical scoping.

But if I call `dog2.bark()` and from within it when `dog1.bark()` is called, shouldn't the value of `this` be dog2? Since the lexical scope of the arrow function is the bark function of dog2? Or am I missing something here?

Would appreciate some clarification on this.
I noticed this question got marked duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095710/methods-in-es6-objects-using-arrow-functions) but I couldnt understand why calling an object from an old-style function still results in the value of `this` being equal to `window`

Comment: *"But if I call dog2.bark() and from within it when dog1.bark() is called, shouldn't the value of this be dog2?"* No, for the same reason it's not `dog1` in `dog1.bark()`. The arrow function closes over the `this` where it was **created**, not the `this` where it was called. See the linked question's answers for details.

Comment: I understand, well thanks, I guess that clears things up a bit

Comment: Think of it this way: It literally does *close over* `this`, exactly like closing over any in-scope identifier. So if you had `var foo = 42; var obj = {m: () => { console.log(foo); } }; function wrapper() { var foo = 67; obj.m(); } wrapper();` Which `foo` does `obj.m` see? Right! The one with 42. Exactly the same thing (literally exactly) with `this`.