# Printing Event Object from an Arrow Function

Tags: node.js, this, arrow-functions

If I want to print the event object in Node.js using a callback function, this works:

### Example 1

```
const events = require( 'events' );

var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

eventEmitter.on( 'customEventNameGoesHere', function() {
    console.log( this );
} );

eventEmitter.emit( 'customEventNameGoesHere' );

/* Sample output:
EventEmitter {
  _events:
   [Object: null prototype] { customEventNameGoesHere: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined }
*/
```

However, if I try using an arrow function, it doesn't work:

### Example 2

```
const events = require( 'events' );

var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

eventEmitter.on( 'customEventNameGoesHere', () => { console.log( this ); } );

eventEmitter.emit( 'customEventNameGoesHere' );

/* Sample output:
{}
*/
```

What do I need to change in Example 2 to print the value of the event object using the keyword "this"? Trying to access the local value of "this" instead of the parent value. How?

Comment: This happens due to lexical scoping. Arrow functions do not bind their own this,they inherit the one from the parent scope.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Methods in ES6 objects: using arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095710/methods-in-es6-objects-using-arrow-functions)

Comment: Is there a way to print the intended value of "this" using an arrow function in this context?

Comment: Its noted in the docs: https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_passing_arguments_and_this_to_listeners

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I read the doc. It talks about the issue, but doesn't explain how to solve it.

Comment: Why do you need the arrow function? If your not needing parent scope?

Comment: Learning about how to work with arrow functions.