# why global object is not being used by arrow function?

Tags: javascript

Below is my code:

```js
let hat = {
    name: "Hat",
    price:"100",
    writeDetails: () =>
        console.log(`${this.name}: ${this.price}`)
};

//setup global variable
name = "global hat"
price = 999;

hat.writeDetails();
```

the output is undefined, undefined

why the global/window object is not injected in this?

Comment: Wherever you’re running it, the `this` isn’t the global object. In the snippet, it is, so that doesn’t help. So… where are you running it?

Comment: @Certain I ran it with node and IDE is VS Code

Comment: @Ry-   I re-editted my post

Comment: “global hat” is a really, really weird thing to do. What’s the real, non-hat problem?

Comment: arrow functions inherit `this` from the scope they are defined in. it's not always global object.

Comment: *"the output is undefined, undefined"*  No, it isn't

Comment: @adiga yes, it is

Comment: Run the snippet. It is not reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of scoping, when arrow function is declared this here is scoped inside the function only.
Use normal function for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is described in [When (and why) you should use ES6 arrow functions — and when you shouldn’t](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26/) section *"Main benefit: No binding of ‘this’"*

You can just avoid using the array function construct:

```
//writeDetails:     () => console.log(`${this.name}: ${this.price}`)
writeDetails: function() {console.log(`${this.name}: ${this.price}`)}
```

Answer (score 0):

An arrow function doesn’t have its own `this`; it inherits the `this` value of where it appears. In your case, that seems to not be the global object.

If you want `writeDetails` to act like a “normal method”, which the properties on `hat` seem to suggest, it shouldn’t be an arrow function:

```
let hat = {
    name: "Hat",
    price: "100",
    writeDetails() {
        console.log(`${this.name}: ${this.price}`);
    },
};
```

Then you can do the odd “global hat” thing with `hat.writeDetails.call(this)`, if you want.

Comment: yes, that's the point, I tried your solution before, but I want to know why it does work in arrow function, but if I rewrte the arrow function, it will work, check my post

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @IronMan Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answers already given. You should read up on [ES6 arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and their [use cases](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26/)

---

Arrow functions are a shorthand method of declaring a function and binding it to the scope it is declared in.

Say a function declared like:

```
class C{
    foo = () => {
        console.log('foo')
    }
}
```

Roughly translates to something like:

```
 class C{
    foo(){
        console.log('foo')
    }
    this.foo = this.foo.bind(this)
 }
```

This causes the function to be binded to the scope it is declared in. In my example, it class C. `this`, if ever used in function `foo` will always point to the class object. In your case, it is declared inside a function, hence, its scope will always be the function itself.

If you declare a function normally without binding it, the `this` context passed to the function will be the context of the block from which you called it from. Say you called your **unbinded** function in `class B`.

In that case, the `this` passed to your function will be pointing to the object of `class B`

So your problem should be solved be declaring your function without a binding. Calling your function from outside any block or class will let your function inherit global scope.

Answer (score 0):

The arrow functions were not intended to replace normal functions which use `function` keyword. For more details [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095710/methods-in-es6-objects-using-arrow-functions).

Here's the working alternative.

```
let hat = {
    nam: "Hat",
    _price: 100,
    priceIncTax: 100 * 1.2,
    set price(newPrice) {
        this._price = newPrice;
        this.priceIncTax = this._price * 1.2;
    },
    get price() {
        return this._price;
    },
    writeDetails(){
        console.log(`${this.nam}: ${this._price}, ${this.priceIncTax}`)}
};

hat.writeDetails();
```