# jQuery $(this).data() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to fix the following code:

```js
const $configuratorMenus = $('.configurators-menu ul li');

$configuratorMenus.click(() => {

    let panelID = $(this).data("id");
    let panelID2 = $(this).attr("data-id");

    console.log(panelID, panelID2);

    //$(`#${panelID}`).slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="configurators-menu">
    <ul>
        <li data-id="shapes">
            <a href="#">
                Shape
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

It keeps consoling `undefined`, what am I doing wrong? I couldn't relate any other solution.

**Note:** I would like to solve this by using the arrow function.

Comment: You are using arrow functions. `this` does not work in arrow functions as in normal function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Methods in ES6 objects: using arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095710/methods-in-es6-objects-using-arrow-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using arrow function , this will refer window object in this case. You can use `e.target`.Where `e` is event object. Also the `data` attribute is on `li` but the event is originating from `a`. So change `$configuratorMenus` to `$('.configurators-menu ul li a')`

```js
const $configuratorMenus = $('.configurators-menu ul li a');

$configuratorMenus.click((e) => {
  // get the parent element from the target
  let panelID = $(e.target).parent().data('id');
  console.log(panelID);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="configurators-menu">
  <ul>
    <li data-id="shapes">
      <a href="#">
                Shape
            </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This one should resolve your problem -

```js
const configuratorMenus = $('.configurators-menu ul li a');

configuratorMenus.click(function () {
    let panelID = $(this).parent().data("id");
    console.log(panelID);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="configurators-menu">
    <ul>
        <li data-id="shapes">
            <a href="#">
                Shape
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```