# Refer `this` in App.vue cause undefined error

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

My App.vue file:

```
<template>
  <v-app app color="grey">
    <Navbar v-if="isLoggedIn"></Navbar>
    <v-content class="mx-4 mb-4">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: { Navbar },

  data: () => {
    return {
      loggedIn: true
    };
  },
  computed: {
    isLoggedIn: () => this.data.loggedIn
  },

  mounted() {
    console.log(process.env);
  },

  created() {}
};
</script>
```

Loading the app in browser I got the error message :

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined"
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: you are using arrow function which doesn't have `this` thats why `undefined` error, so you need to use **ES5** style of methods.

Comment: The accepted answer does not work and will throw an error  https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/nq1b74va/

Comment: @Dan the point here is changing es6 arrow function to normal javascript function. The error is originated from my original post, my real cose is actually this: `return this.$store.state.auth.username !== null;`. Following the the approach I get my code working now. Literally your answer is more comprehensive, but kaleidawave's answer is 2m earlier than yours

Comment: @GelinLuo - There are 2 equally breaking errors in your code.  `this.data` will not work in any context, arrow functions or not.  Future readers who copy the syntax from that answer will have errors

Comment: @Dan makes sense. I marked your answer as accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```js
computed: {
  isLoggedIn: () => this.data.loggedIn
}
```

to

```js
computed: {
  isLoggedIn() {
    return this.loggedIn;
  } 
}
```

- Don't use an es6 arrow function or `this` will lose access to the proper object.  Here is a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31095976/2185093) on Stack Overflow about that.
- `this.data` has to be used as `this.$data` (otherwise it's looking for a `data` property on the `data` property), but don't do that either: you actually don't need to reference `data` at all, and can go directly to the variable

Answer (score 1):

Using a arrow function creates a anonymous function which means `this` is bound to `window` and not the vue instance. Using `function` ensures the value of `this` is the vue instance. So change the `isLoggedIn` computed property to:

```js
computed: {
    isLoggedIn: function() { return this.data.loggedIn }
}

// or

computed: {
    isLoggedIn() { return this.data.loggedIn }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why we can't use arrow functions?

Comment: @Mrkinix Please refer to Dan's answer below for why arrow function can't be use in this context