# JS Calling functions from a nested object inside this object

Tags: javascript, jsobject

actually im trying to run the following code:

```js
var myObj = {
  subObj: {
    methodA: (parA) => {
      this.methodB(parA); //This is not working
    },
    methodB: (parB) => {
      console.log(parB);
    }
  }
}

myObj.subObj.methodA('Hello World');
```

i get the error "Uncaught TypeError: this.methodB is not a function".

Why am i getting this error? Isn't "methodB" in scope of methodA via 'this'?

Thank you very much

Comment: No, it is not scoped to the object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Methods in ES6 objects: using arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095710/methods-in-es6-objects-using-arrow-functions)

Comment: Also relevant:[Self-references in object literals / initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow functions don't have separate [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this).

Hence doing

```
var myObj = {
  subObj: {
    methodA: (parA) => {
      this.methodB(parA); // `this` will always be window / outer context as arrow functions will not bind `this` at runtime.
    },
    methodB: (parB) => {
      console.log(parB);
    }
  }
}


myObj.subObj.methodA('Hello World'); // fails as `this.methodB` in your `methodA` is equivalent to `window.methodB` which is not present
```

is similar to doing:

```
var myObj = {
  subObj: {
    methodA: function(parA) {
      this.methodB(parA);
    },
    methodB: function(parB) {
      console.log(parB);
    }
  }
}

myObj.subObj.methodA.call(window || {}, 'Hello World');  // where window || {} is the lexical / outer scope to your function.
```

---

In the latter's case, things will work when you do the following:

```
myObj.subObj.methodA('Hello World');
```

> Since normal functions use `this` of the caller and you call `methodA` as `myObj.subObj.methodA`, `this` = `myObj.subObj`. Hence `this.methodB` is available as it's equivalent to `myObj.subObj.methodB`

Answer (score 1):

Arrow functions have special binding. The value of `this` in arrow functions is equivalent to the value of this where the function was defined(lexical scope). In this situation window(in browsers). To make your function work, use regular functions where `this` references the enclosing context:

```
var myObj = {
  subObj: {
    methodA: function (parA) {
      this.methodB(parA); //This is not working
    },
    methodB: function (parB) {
      console.log(parB);
    }
  }
}

myObj.subObj.methodA('Hello World');
```

More on this is [explained here](https://medium.com/tfogo/advantages-and-pitfalls-of-arrow-functions-a16f0835799e#:~:text=Arrow%20functions%20and%20this,this%20in%20their%20lexical%20scope.&text=The%20context%20is%20(roughly)%20the%20object%20that%20calls%20the%20function.).

Comment: You can also use shorthand method syntax `methodA(parA)` instead of `methodA: function (parA)`

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be, that it is because all of these are anonymous, non-scoped, non-instantiated objects and `this` actually refers to the window object.