# Why isn't this.key working properly in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```js
let student = {
    

fname: "Carlos",
    lname: 'Dubón',
    sayHi(){
        alert(`Hi my name is ${this.fname}`);
    },
    sayBye: function() {
        alert(`Bye ${this.fname}`);
    },
    sayHiAgain: ()=> {
        alert(`Hi my name is ${this.fname}`);
    }
}

student.sayHiAgain();
```

I'm new to OOP in Javascript, I understand that the 3 ways in which I wrote a method work exactly the same.

`student.sayHi();` works and shows up the alert => "Hi my name is Carlos"

but `student.sayHiAgain();` shows up the alert => "Hi my name is undefined"

What am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-exchangeable)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Methods in ES6 objects: using arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095710/methods-in-es6-objects-using-arrow-functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using arrow functions, it uses lexical scoping meaning that it refers to it's current scope and no further past that, i.e., binds to the inner-function and not to the object itself.

> An arrow function expression is a syntactically compact alternative to
> a regular function expression, although without its own bindings to
> the this, arguments, super, or new.target keywords. Arrow function
> expressions are ill suited as methods, and they cannot be used as
> constructors.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 0):

[Arrow functions have no “this”](https://javascript.info/arrow-functions#arrow-functions-have-no-this)

> Arrow functions are special: they don’t have their “own” this. If we
> reference this from such a function, it’s taken from the outer
> “normal” function.

```js
let student = {
  fname: "Carlos",
  lname: "Dubón",
  sayHi: function () {
    console.log(`Hi my name is ${this.fname}`);
  },
  sayBye: function () {
    console.log(`Bye ${this.fname}`);
  },
  sayHiAgain: function () {
    console.log(`Hi my name is ${this.fname}`);
  },
};

student.sayHiAgain();
```

[Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)