# how to fire custom event in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have created custom event for mousestop , but i am not able to fire the component methods from the custom event.
below is the html code

```
<div class="col-md-12 img-div" #imageCanvas>
            <img id="srcImg" #srcImg class="crf-img" (click)="createOverlay($event)"
                src="../../assets/aCRF-PRV111_CLN-001 v1.4-images/aCRF-PRV111_CLN-001 v1.blank_0.jpg">
</div>
```

below is the component.ts code.

```
ngOnInit() {
    (function (mouseStopDelay) {
      var timeout;
      document.getElementById('srcImg').addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
          var event = new CustomEvent("mousestop", {
            detail: {
              clientX: e.clientX,
              clientY: e.clientY
            },
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true
          });
          e.target.dispatchEvent(event);
        }, mouseStopDelay);
      });
    }(2000));

    document.getElementById('srcImg').addEventListener('mousestop', function (e) {
      // console.log('You stopped your mouse while on the link');
      console.log('Mouse stopped and coordinates are: ', (e as any).detail.clientX, (e as any).detail.clientY);
      
        this.onMouseMove((e as any).detail.clientX, (e as any).detail.clientY);
    });
  }
  onMouseMove(x: number, y: number) {
    ----some code here--- 
  }
```

but i am getting below error

```
ERROR TypeError: this.onMouseMove is not a function
    at HTMLImageElement.<anonymous> (eimage.component.ts:75)
```

Kindly let me know how to resolve it.
I have implemented same in ngAfterViewInit also but i am facing same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) instead of an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#:%7E:text=An%20arrow%20function%20expression%20is,cannot%20be%20used%20as%20constructors.) `() => {}`. For that reason your `this` changes. Change

```
document.getElementById('srcImg').addEventListener('mousestop', function (e) {
```

to

```
document.getElementById('srcImg').addEventListener('mousestop', (e) => {
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095710/) you can find additional info on that topic.

Comment: I agree. Using the fat arrow function transfers the context (`this`) inside the function.