# How to call another function inside function in export default?

Tags: javascript, function, module, es6-modules

```js
export default {
 one: () => {
  //some codes
 },
 two: () => {
  //some codes
  one(); // error
  this.one(); // error
 }
}
```

I have module like that, and I want to call function one() inside function two().
But I got error like this : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'one' of undefined`.
How can I fix it? I want to know the cause.

Comment: Extract them out into separate functions and then include them in the export?

Comment: "*I want to know the cause.*" see [Methods in ES6 objects: using arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31095710) and for a more general overview: [Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / interchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379) + [Self-references in object literals / initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4616202)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about extracting them out into separate functions and then include them in the export?

```js
const one = () => {
  //some codes
};

const two = () => {
  //some codes
  one();
};

export default {
 one,
 two
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn´t use arrows function if you want to give a new context to the `this` keyword.

Look this example, it uses an arrow function in the `two` method. It would return error since the `this` keyword is not related to the object, but mantains the context from the last function.

```js
let obj = {
  one: function() {
    console.log("one");
  },
  two: () => {     // Arrow function
   this.one();
  }
}

obj.two();
```

If you use a normal function, the `this` keyword would be related to the object:

```js
let obj = {
  one: function() {
    console.log("one");
  },
  two: function() {     // Normal function
   this.one();
  }
}

obj.two();
```

This is the main difference between arrow functions and normal functions