# createRef().current is coming as null in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so basically my usecase is that when i click the download button present in each row of the table, my data returned should be downloaded via CSV.
I'm creating the ref like this

```
class ViewStorageGroups extends Component {

    csvLink = React.createRef();
```

This is my custom component which renders a table

```
 <TableWithHeaders
                tableHeaders = {tableData.tableHeaders}
                rowData = {tableData.rowData}
                formatter = {tableData.formatter}
                handleClick = {this.handleClick}
                clickable = {tableData.clickable}
                page = {rowsPerPage}
                rowsPerPage = {rowsPerPage}
                handlePageChange = {this.handlePageChange}
                handleChangeRowsPerPage = {this.handleChangeRowsPerPage}

            />
```

this is my handleClick function which gets called when i press the download button

```
handleClick = (rowData, clickComponent,e) => {
        const storageGroupDto = StorageGroupHelpers.convertStorageGroupDataToDto(rowData)
        this.setState({groupDataDownloadResp: storageGroupDto}, () =>  this.csvLink.current.link.click())
    }
```

and i'm using React's CSVLink component to download the data as csv.

```
renderDownloadedData  = () => {
const fileName = createFileNameForCSVDownload('STORAGE_GROUP_DOWNLOAD', getWarehouseIdFromRedux(this.props))

return (
    <div>
        <CSVLink
            ref={this.csvLink}
            data={this.state.groupDataDownloadResp}
            filename={fileName}
            target='_blank'
        />
    </div>
)
```

}
Now the issue is when handleClick is triggered, my `this.csvLink.current` is coming as null. the same implementation is present at other places in my codebase and working fine correct. i'm not able to figure out where i'm going wrong
I have also tried initialising `csvLink = React.createRef();` at componenentDidMount and the constructor but still the same error is occuring.

Answer (score 0):

finally got the issue but not sure the Reason.
if i use

```
<CSVLink
                ref={this.csvLink}
                data={this.state.groupDataDownloadResp}
                filename={fileName}
                target='_blank'
            />
```

inside a arrow function like this

```
 renderDownloadedData  = () => {
    const fileName = createFileNameForCSVDownload('STORAGE_GROUP_DOWNLOAD', getWarehouseIdFromRedux(this.props))

    return (
        <div>
            <CSVLink
                ref={this.csvLink}
                data={this.state.groupDataDownloadResp}
                filename={fileName}
                target='_blank'
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

and then call this inside render like this

```
render () {
 return (
  {this.renderDownloadedData()}
 )
}
```

It returns reactRef()'s current value as null. however if I dont use arrow function and use the function like this `renderDownloadedData ()`, it works perfectly fine. if someone can explain me the reason i would be very grateful

Comment: No pun intended, but **this** may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095710/methods-in-es6-objects-using-arrow-functions