# Arrow function undefined

Tags: javascript, html

Does anyone know why the function without the arrow is showing the name value, but if use arrow function is showing the message undefined ?

Without the arrow function:

```
 const test = {
    prop: 42,
    name: "Leo",
    func: function(){
         return this.name
     },
   };

  console.log(test.func());
```

With the arrow function:

```
 const test = {
    prop: 42,
    name: "Leo",
    func: function() => this.name,
   };

  console.log(test.func());
```

Here is showing the message: undefined

Comment: Check the declaration of arrow function. @Spectric 's answer will be solve your issue.

Comment: Because arrow functions [don't have a `function` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: [Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / interchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379) | [Methods in ES6 objects: using arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31095710)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not [how you declare an arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Remove the `function` part:

```js
const test = {
  prop: 42,
  name: "Leo",
  func: () => this.name,
};

console.log(test.func());
```