# How to rewrite class to plain object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, object

How would one rewrite this class to a plain object?

```
class ExampleClass {
    firstPropery: number = 0;
    secondProperty!: string;

  async exampleMethod(): Promise<void> {
    const { secondProperty } = await SomeHelperClass.exampleRequest();
    this.secondProperty = secondProperty;
  }
}
```

I would think it's something similar as this

```
interface IExample {
  firstProperty: number;
  secondProperty: string;
  exampleMethod: () => Promise<void>;
}

const Example: IExample = {
  firstProperty: 0,
  exampleMethod: async (): Promise<void> => {
    const { secondProperty } = await SomeHelperClass.exampleRequest();
    ...
  }
}
```

But how to set the `secondProperty` via the `exampleMethod`? In the class method I can just write `this.secondProperty = ...`, which I cannot do in the plain object.

My second question is, with the class I would make a new object like this `const newObject = new ExampleClass();`. With the plain object way, how would I make a new object instance?

Any help is gladly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the class method I can just write `this.secondProperty = ...`, which I cannot do in the plain object.

Actually you can. It doesn't matter whether it's defined in a class or object literal, `exampleMethod` is still a method and when called as `example.exampleMethod()` it will have its `this` point to `example`. However, [you cannot use an arrow function to define it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31095710/1048572) - use method syntax instead:

```
const example: IExample = {
  firstProperty: 0,
  async exampleMethod(): Promise<void> {
    const { secondProperty } = await SomeHelperClass.exampleRequest();
    ...
  }
}
```

> With the class I would make a new object like this `const newObject = new ExampleClass();`. With the plain object way, how would I make a new object instance?

You write the code again and again. Or you use `Object.assign` to copy the method onto a new object. Or you place the object literal inside a function that you can call multiple times.

Comment: Ah, thank you, that works wonderful.

However, the thing is in the class I don't set `secondProperty` immediately, but it is set when called like this: `const exObj = new ExampleClass();` and `exObj.exampleMethod();`. In the class way, I could just write `secondProperty!: string` since I know it will never be null or undefined, because I always call the `exampleMethod()` to set it up... but TypeScript complains that `secondProperty` is missing (since its defined in the interface) with the plain object way and it does not let me set the exclamation thingy. What to do there?

Comment: @PTheory "*I know it will never be null or undefined*" - actually you're wrong there and TypeScript is right. Even if you immediately call the `exampleMethod`, the `exampleRequest` is asynchronous and until that promise fulfills, `secondProperty` stays `undefined`. If you want to make the same mistake in the object literal, it's `secondProperty: undefined!`, but I wouldn't recommend that :-)

Comment: @PTheory My recommendation would be to remove the `exampleMethod` from the interface, and instead write a `getExample(): Promise<Example>` function that does the request and returns a promise for the `Example` instance with first and second property.