# How to convert a function to arrow function inside an object

Tags: javascript, function, object, arrow-functions

```
let object = {
    name : "Aditya",
    age : 20,
    printIt : function(){
        console.log(this.name + " " + this.age)
    }
}
```

in above object i want to change printIt function in to an arrow function i tried as below but it is not working.

```
let object = {
    name : "Aditya",
    age : 20,
    printIt =  () => {
        console.log(this.name + " " + this.age)
    }
}
```

how can we change the printIt function to arrow function in side this object

Comment: Be aware that the context of `this` inside an arrow function is different. More info here: [Methods in ES6 objects: using arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095710/methods-in-es6-objects-using-arrow-functions)

Comment: If you just want a shorter syntax, there is one that happens to be the most appropriate syntax for this use case, aynway: [method definitions](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions).

Answer (score 0):

Use a colon `:` like in `name` and `age`.

```js
let object = {
      name: "Aditya",
      age: 20,
      printIt: () => {
          console.log(this.name + " " + this.age)
      }
  }
 
object.printIt();
```

Altough because of the arrow function, `this` doens't work like you expect it to. Simply use the traditional `function` syntax and the `this` will work like expected.

```js
let otherObject = {
      name: "Aditya",
      age: 20,
      printIt: function() {
          console.log(this.name + " " + this.age)
      }
  }
  
otherObject.printIt();
```

Another solution would be to call `object.name` and `object.age` within the printIt function of the first code example, but that's not best practice as the arrow function has to be changed when you rename the `object`.