# what's wrong with this code ? I got undefined

Tags: javascript-objects

Code:

```
const john = { fullName: 'johny Rodes', mass: 92, height: 1.95, calcBMI: ()=>{ this.bmi = this.mass / this.height ** 2; return this.bmi; } };
john.calcBMI();
console.log(john.bmi);
```

Comment: What do you get in console.log(john)?

Answer (score 1):

Arrow functions in javascript inherit from that calling scope, so `this` actually refers to the global `this` in your case, not the `john` object.

```js
const john = {
    fullName: 'johny Rodes', 
    mass: 92, 
    height: 1.95,
    // calcBMI is an arrow function, so "this" is bound to the calling state
    calcBMI: () => { 
        this.bmi = this.mass / this.height ** 2; 
        return this.bmi; 
    },
    // "this" in calcBMI2 refers to this object
    calcBMI2() { 
        this.bmi = this.mass / this.height ** 2; 
        return this.bmi; 
    },

};
```

As `mass` and `height` do not exist in the calling scope, the arrow function results in `undefined`. However, the regular function inherits the scope of the class it belongs to.

```js
john.calcBMI(); 
console.log(john.bmi); // => undefined

john.calcBMI2();
console.log(john.bmi); // => 24.194608809993426
```

If you were to set mass and height outside of the function call, it would now work.

```js
const this.mass = 92;
const this.height = 1.95;

// the "this" in the current scope is not the "john" object
john.calcBMI();
console.log(john.bmi); // => 24.194608809993426
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095710/methods-in-es6-objects-using-arrow-functions) which touches on the same subject