# this not binding as expected

Tags: javascript, typescript, this

I have an example that appears to me to be identical to the example given in the [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#try_it)

```
const foo = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        name: "Personal Files",
        onSelect: function() {
            dispatch({
                type: MoveDocActionType.ENTER_PARTITION,
                partitionName: this.name
            })
        }
    }
}
console.log(foo(({type, partitionName})=>console.log(partitionName)).onSelect())
// Expected output "Personal Files"
```

The Mozilla docs example:

```
const test = {
   prop: 42,
   func: function() {
     return this.prop;
   },
 };

console.log(test.func());
// expected output: 42
```

However, during actual execution, `this` is undefined in my case.
What am I missing, as this seems to be identical to the docs, so I don't see why I would need to manually call bind or anything like that.

EDIT:
Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal)

The way I was actually calling the method was closer to this:

```
const foo = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        name: "Personal Files",
        onSelect: function() {
            dispatch({
                type: MoveDocActionType.ENTER_PARTITION,
                partitionName: this.name
            })
        }
    }
}
const bar = foo(({type, partitionName})=>console.log(partitionName)).onSelect
console.log(bar()

// Expected output "Personal Files"
```

Comment: use arrow functions, `function` keyword functions don't bind `this` to the enclosing scope, rather, `this` is determined when the call is made

Comment: "*during actual execution, this is undefined in my case*" [I cannot reproduce it](https://jsbin.com/vusigutobu/edit?js,console). Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Dummy if `onSelect` is an arrow function, typescript doesn't seem to think `this` is bound to anything at all.

The docs also seem to suggest otherwise:
```
'use strict';

var obj = { // does not create a new scope
  i: 10,
  b: () => console.log(this.i, this),
  c: function() {
    console.log(this.i, this);
  }
}

obj.b(); // prints undefined, Window {...} (or the global object)
obj.c(); // prints 10, Object {...}
```

Comment: @Dummy you're completely wrong here. An arrow function would not use the object *currently being instantiated* as the value of `this`, since the 1. that object *does not exist while it's being instantiated*. 2. It's not even the value of `this` even if it the arrow function was instantiated later. See [Methods in ES6 objects: using arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31095710) and [Self-references in object literals / initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4616202)

Comment: @VLAZ thank you for pointing this out! It turns out, my problem was that I wasn't actual calling the object the way I showed, and was passing the method reference to something else that would call it. So when it was eventually called, this was indeed `undefined`.

Comment: See [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429) and [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484). Yes, dissociating the call from the the object it's called *on* would give you the wrong value of `this`. With your code [something like this](https://jsbin.com/qudakudawo/edit?js,console) would work to keep the call with the object it's called on. Or [like so](https://jsbin.com/xopirehibo/1/edit?js,console) to make it not depend on `this`.

Answer (score -1):

If you remove the first console.log, it works for me :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
const foo = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        name: "Personal Files",
        onSelect: function() {
            dispatch({
                type: "Toto",
                partitionName: this.name
            })
        }
    }
}
foo(({type, partitionName})=>console.log(partitionName)).onSelect()
</script>
```

Comment: The `undefined` printed in the console from the outer `console.log()` is ***not*** the value of `this` inside `onSelect`