# Empty list when running request

Tags: javascript

I have a simple HTTP request with javascript that uses the `await` feature, however, I get the following result:

> {}
> undefined

When I run the function, I have tested the headers and url with python and it works successfully with `requests` am I missing something here?

```
import pkg from 'superagent';
const { get } = pkg;

const header =  {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.4 Safari/605.1.15'
};
const url =  'https://books.toscrape.com';

class Agent {
    constructor(url, headers){
        this.url = url;
        this.headers = headers;
        
    }
    
    getAgent = async () => {
        const res = await get(this.url)
            .set(this.headers);
            return res.body;
    }
};

const request = new Agent(url, header);

console.log(await request.getAgent());
```

I.e. this works successfully in python:

```
import requests

header =  {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.4 Safari/605.1.15'
};
url =  'https://books.toscrape.com';

print(requests.get(url, header).content)
```

Comment: `getAgent()` doesn't *return* anything, it just logs a value to the console.  It's not clear to me which you want to do... Do you want `getAgent()` to internally log its value to the console, or do you want it to return its value and consuming code log it to the console?

Comment: @David I prefer to return its value and consume code log to the console.

Comment: Then `return res.body` instead of `console.log(res.body)` ?  To return something from a function, one uses the `return` statement.

Comment: @David sure, I have tested this before however it returns nothing when I await it with the outer console.log

Comment: Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates this?  In the code shown it's not returning anything simply because it doesn't `return` anything.

Comment: @David I am very new to Javascript so I may be missing simple syntax here

Comment: Don't use an arrow function for methods, they don't receive `this`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Methods in ES6 objects: using arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095710/methods-in-es6-objects-using-arrow-functions)

Comment: @EssXTee No this is not the error I am getting, In fact I do not get an error, I just get an empty list returned. I have tried Barmar suggestion and still an empty list. Although the suggestion was very helpful as it did jog my memory for `this`, I remember this during a codeacademy class months ago.