# Javascript: update an object from its method without this keyword

Tags: javascript

I am working with a library which implement a class `Graph` that have a method `Graph.registerNode()`

The methode has the following signature.

```js
Graph.registerNode('node-name', {
  object: {
    options: {
      key: "value"
    },
  updateOption: () => {
   this.options = { key: "other value" }
  }
})
```

Is it possible to update the `options` key from `updateOptions` without using the `this` keyword?

Comment: Do you understand that executing `updateOption` won't change the value of `object.options.key` - so, you need code that does what you want in the first place before wondering if there's a different way to do it

Comment: [Not even your current code that uses `this` does work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31095710/1048572)

Comment: Indeed, the library uses traditional function signature. So I guess, using this keyword is the only way to reference the object from its method?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const options = {
    key: "value"
};

Graph.registerNode('node-name', {
    object: {
        options,
    }
    updateOption: () => {
        options.key = "other value";
    }
})
```

How about this?

Comment: That was my first thought. But once the `registerNode` method is called, and the node is registered, any call of updateOptions method will not update the `{ object: { options } }`. I think both object and updateOption are handled internally at the same time by the registerNode method.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this via a factory function

```js
const factoryFunction = () => {
  let options: {
    key: "value"
  }
  
  return Object.freeze({
    updateOption: () => {
      options = {
        key: 'updated value',
      }
    },
    printOption: () => {
      console.log(options)
    }
  })
}

const config = factoryFunction()

Graph.registerNode('node-name', config)
```