# vuejs call anonymous function in mounted method

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, graphql

I´m trying to do a function in the method with vuejs 2 and call this function inside `mounted()` but it returns- **Error in the mounted hook: "TypeError: this.getFormula is not a function"**

I´m doing an apollo query in this method to fill one array and return data to my component.

```
mounted() {
    if (this.$route.params.id_tipo_liquidacion) {
      this.tipoLiquidacion_id = this.$route.params.id_tipo_liquidacion;
      this.grupoId = Number(this.$route.params.id_agrupacion);
    }
    if (this.$route.params.id_tipo_seccion_liquidacion) {
      this.tipoSeccionLiquidacion_id = this.$route.params.id_tipo_seccion_liquidacion;
      this.grupoId = Number(this.$route.params.id_agrupacion);
    }

    this.getFormula()
  },
  method: {
    getFormula: () => ({
        fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
        query: gql`query formulas($id: ID!){
                        formula(id: $formula_id){
                                myDBdata
                        }
                    }`,
        variables() {
          return {
            id: parseInt(myBeforeArray.id),
          }
        },
      }).then(response => {
        this.formula = response.data

        console.log(this.formula)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error-> ');
        console.log(error);
      })
  })
}
```

And the problem it´s that I can´t call my function.

**UPDATE-**

After the response @Mati y has this problem now:

```
Error in the mounted hook: "TypeError: {(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)}.then is not a function"
```

Comment: Use `methods` instead of `method`.

Comment: @Mati thanks for your response. Now i have other problem. Update my question

Comment: Well if you look closely, you are chaining `then` on a non-promise object.

Comment: @Mati thanks for your response. How i can solve it¿? i don´t know very much graphql

Comment: I'd suggest starting with going through docs for Vue Apollo, especially everything in regards to queries.

Comment: Arrow and regular functions aren't interchangeable, certainly not in cases that involve `this`

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095710/methods-in-es6-objects-using-arrow-functions