# Javascript prototype function like Kotlin extensions

Tags: javascript, oop, prototypal-inheritance, prototype-programming, kotlin-extension

I wonder if Javascript Prototype can extend class like Kotlin Extension does.
Example:

```
fun MutableList<Int>.swap(index1: Int, index2: Int) {
    val tmp = this[index1] // 'this' corresponds to the list
    this[index1] = this[index2]
    this[index2] = tmp
}
```

we can receive the object using `this` keyword, but I can't figure out how to do it in JavaScript.

I have tried `this`, but I'm out of clue how can I receive the object?
It's just giving me Windows object.

```js
Map.prototype.isValid = () => {
    return this
}
```

Thanks in advance

(edited)
I already read [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095710/methods-in-es6-objects-using-arrow-functions) which is so different with my case.
I'm trying to extend [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) class which is standard built-it objects.

Comment: "*this solution is so different with my case*" - no. Your problem is that you are trying to use an arrow function as a method, which does not work. Use a normal `function` and the `this` keyword will refer to the instance that the method was called on as expected.