# "this" and object literals in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
var v = {
    foo: (function () {
        return this;
    }.bind(this))
};
```

What is the value of `this` when passed to the `bind` invocation (and why)?

Comment: Depends on what `this` is. Which has nothing to do with object literals.

Comment: Haha. Say the code is run in the global context in a browser.

Comment: Well, then `this`  is the global object.

Comment: It's whatever `this` is at the moment `bind()` is called. If that's global, then it's global.

Comment: Why not try yourself ?

Comment: "this" will be the window object because when declaring *var v = ..* v becomae an property in the window object.

Comment: @ElheniMokhles not an attribute, but a property, but I know what you meant...

Comment: yes yes a property :)

Comment: or perhaps [How does the “this” keyword in Javascript act within an object literal?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13441307/1048572) is a better dupe

Comment: Assuming it's not strict more