# Can access an attribute of my object but not a function

Tags: javascript

I have to figure out, how to develop oop-javascript the right way. I read a lot about `prototypes` but the internet explained to me, I need it only, if I create an object a lot of times. But my `SuperInterface` exists only once. So I created it as an object:

```
var SuperInterface = {
    superaction: function () {
        alert(1);
    },
    actions: [{
        title: 'This is great',
        do_this: this.superaction
    }],
    init: function () {
        console.log(this.actions[0].title);
        this.actions[0].do_this();
    }
};
SuperInterface.init();
```

Running `init()` puts the `title` successfully to the console. But the alert is never called. I do not understand, why not? What should I change?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value of `this` in the middle of that object initializer is **not** a reference to the object that is "under construction". There is no way to get such a reference during initialization since the object doesn't yet exist, and nor would you reference it with `this`. So you really can't initialize a property like that.  You can however split it out into a separate statement:

```
var SuperInterface = {
    superaction: function () {
        alert(1);
    },
    actions: [{
        title: 'This is great',
        do_this: null;
    }],
    init: function () {
        console.log(this.actions[0].title);
        this.actions[0].do_this();
    }
};
SuperInterface.actions[0].do_this = SuperInterface.superaction;
```

Comment: _There is no way to get such a reference._ See my answer.

Comment: @Vidul that does work in this case, but it's still true that there's no way to obtain a reference to an object in the middle of the object literal that describes it.

Comment: I don't see how your statement relates to a possible fix. I also don't see how your statement _There is no way to get such a reference_ is not false.

Comment: @Vidul Can you show me an example of how it's possible to obtain a reference to an object that's "under construction"? Your solution is a good one, but (A) it does not involve getting a reference to the object *while it is under construction*, and (B) it will stop working if the variable "SuperInterface" takes on a new value. There simply is no way to do it in JavaScript; the language does not provide a mechanism for it (at least, not in ES5).

Comment: _(B) it will stop working if the variable "SuperInterface" takes on a new value_ ?! Please elaborate.

Comment: Your code relies on the reference to "SuperInterface" in the anonymous function. That's not necessarily a bad thing, and I think your solution is a good one, but it's just a fact that if that variable changes, the meaning of your "do_this" wrapper function would change because it always refers to that variable.

Comment: @Vidul [Here is a fork of your jsfiddle to illustrate what I mean.](https://jsfiddle.net/gv4fut62/)

Answer (score 2):

If you debug this code, you will find `SuperInterface.actions[0].do_this`  is `undefined` 
The reason is quite obvious. At the time of evaluation of code.

```
  actions: [{
        title: 'This is great',
        do_this: this.superaction
    }]
```

this.superaction, here `this` points to the window object.

and in this window object superaction does'nt exits..

To make this work eventually you need to

```
var SuperInterface = {
    superaction: function () {
        alert(1);
    },
    actions: [{
        title: 'This is great',
        do_this: null
    }],
    init: function () {
        console.log(this.actions[0].title);
        this.actions[0].do_this();
    }
};
SuperInterface.actions[0].do_this = SuperInterface.superaction;
SuperInterface.init();
```

I hope you got the answer. 
Thanks

Comment: `this` is never a reference to any part of any objects being initialized. It's whatever it is in the context of the outer `var` declaration. Object initializer expressions do not affect `this`, in other words.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var SuperInterface = {
    superaction: function () {
        alert(1);
    },
    actions: [{
        title: 'This is great',
        do_this: function() {
          return SuperInterface.superaction();
        }
    }],
    init: function () {
        console.log(this.actions[0].title);
        this.actions[0].do_this();
    }
};
SuperInterface.init();
```

`this` in your case refers to the literal object inside the array `actions` - it does not contain the method `superaction`.

Comment: I'm guessing the downvote is for your final remark. `this` refers to the global object.

Comment: @KingMob Is this so? Test it: put `console.log(this);` in `do_this`.

Comment: In the original Q. it is the global object (assuming no other context).

Comment: @KingMob I don't get your point. _Pointy: There is no way to get such a reference._ Wrong - there is a way, that is my point.

Comment: You're saying that `this` in `do_this: this.superaction` in the Q. refers to `SuperInterface.actions[0]`, which is wrong.

Comment: @Vidul Perhaps I am not explaining the issue clearly. In an object literal, *without reference to any symbols outside the object*, there is no way to obtain a reference to the object being constructed.

Comment: **'In the original Q.'** By invoking a method you're changing the `this` value.

Comment: The value of `this` is **never** affected by an object literal expression. The **only** thing that sets `this` is function invocation or entry into a "global" scope. An object literal does not change `this`.

Comment: In your JSFiddle, the function is called *after* the object has been constructed. The value of `this` is what it is because of that function call being made.

Comment: @Pointy Obviously we are mixing the topics. I don't deny your statements except this one: `There is no way to get such a reference`.

Comment: @Vidul it's a hard concept to communicate. Your anonymous function can get a reference, that is true - but it gets the reference **after** the object has been constructed. You obviously know JavaScript so that seems really obvious probably, but this question comes up a lot on StackOverflow. People expect `this` to refer to the object being built, which is not crazy or dumb but it's just not how JavaScript works.

Comment: @Pointy Everything seems hard if you don't know the concrete answer to a question.