# Node.js module "this" resets

Tags: node.js, module

PlayerTracker.js:

```
var util = require('util');
var PlayerTracker = function(GameServer, pos) {
  this.gs = GameServer;
  this.pos = pos;
  this.left = false;
  this.right = false;
  console.log("constructor" + util.inspect(this));
};

PlayerTracker.prototype.getPos = function() {
  return this.pos;
};

PlayerTracker.prototype.setPos = function() {
  return this.pos;
};

PlayerTracker.prototype.setLeft = function(left) {
  this.left = left;
};
PlayerTracker.prototype.setRight = function(left) {
  this.right = left;
};

PlayerTracker.prototype.moveTick = function() {
  console.log(util.inspect(this));
  if (this.left) {
    if (this.pos <= 0) {

    } else {
      this.pos--;
      this.left = false;
    }
  } else if (this.right) {
    if (this.pos >= 10) {

    } else {
      this.pos++;
      this.right = false;
    }
  }
};
module.exports = PlayerTracker;
```

At the Start i get:

```
constructor{ gs:       
{ config: { serverPort: 1010, testValue: 0 },
 socketServer:
  { domain: null,
    _events: [Object],
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _server: [Object],
    _closeServer: [Function],
    options: [Object],
    path: null,
    clients: [Object] } },
  pos: 5,
  left: false,
  right: false }
```

but then after i call MoveTick, i get:

```
{ _idleTimeout: 500,
_idlePrev: null,
_idleNext: null,
_idleStart: 4060813,
_onTimeout: [Function: wrapper],
_repeat: true }
```

It looks like the this varibale resets.
I simply open it with `var playerTracker = new PlayerTracker(this,5)`
and call it with `setInterval(playerTracker.moveTick,500)`
I just want to keep the position and so on.
Do you know any reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to do:

```
setInterval(function(){playerTracker.moveTick()},500);
```

or:

```
setInterval(playerTracker.moveTick.bind(playTracker),500);
```

That's because the value of `this` in javascript depends on how you call the method.

When you do:

```
setInterval(playerTracker.moveTick,500);
```

What you're really doing is:

```
var x = playerTracker.moveTick;
setInterval(x,500);
```

Thus the `setInterval` is calling your function without the `playTracker` object. In which case the `moveTick` function is called as a regular function. And depending on weather or not you're in strict mode `this` is either undefined or the global object (`window` in browsers).

See this related answer for a complete (and up-to-date) description of how `this` works: [How does the "this" keyword in Javascript act within an object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal/13441628#13441628)

Comment: you need to use the brackets in your first option... `setInterval(function(){playerTracker.moveTick()},500);`

Comment: @user1936097: Thanks for spotting that!

Answer (score 0):

When you call `setInterval(playerTacker.moveTick, 500)` what is happening is that the function `moveTick` is being called in a different context after 500ms, and the value of `this` will be an object pointing to the probably the interval timeout controller.

To make it run as you intend, you need to make sure the function is run in the context of the correct instance of the class `PlayerTracker`

try this:
`setInterval(function(){playerTracker.moveTick()}, 500)`