# How does "this" work, in the context of onclick events? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I understand how `this` works when invoked on an object, but I'm having trouble understanding how `this` works when called from a "static" context.

Given the following HTML:

```
<body onload="myOnLoad()">
    <div id="someDiv">0</div>
</body>
```

...and this javascript:

```
function myOnLoad() {
    var inc = new Incrementer();
    /*** increase() works fine here, "this" refers to "inc" ***/
    inc.increase();
    inc.setOnClick();
}

function Incrementer() {
    this.value = 0;
}

Incrementer.prototype.setOnClick = function() {
    /*** increase fails to update someDiv when clicked.
         "this" is not "inc"   ***/
    document.getElementById("someDiv").onclick = this.increase;
}

Incrementer.prototype.increase = function() {
    document.getElementById("someDiv").innerHTML = ++this.value;
}
```

...clicking on `someDiv` turns it's innerHTML into `NaN`.  I realize that this is because the onclick event is unaware of the existence of `inc`, but what I don't understand is how to pass 'inc' into the onclick event.

**Do you know how I can access `inc`'s variables from the context of an onclick?  Or, is there a more conventional way of doing this?**

**I'm mostly interested in learning how I can make `someDiv`'s onclick refer to that specific instance, `inc`.**

Comment: If you think you know how `this` works based on experience from other languages then you don't know how it works. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal/13441628#13441628

Comment: Thanks for the insight @slebetman. As I mentioned in my very first sentence, I don't fully understand how `this` works in javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` refers to the context of where the function being called, e.g. in `setOnClick` the function `this.increase` will be called in the context of `someDiv`, so `this.value` would be undefined in that case.

try

```
document.getElementById("someDiv").onclick = this.increase.bind(this);
```

You may want to learn more about the property of `this` from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Awesome, thanks for adding the link as well!   I'll check that out too.

Answer (score 0):

In event handlers, `this` is bound to the element that triggered the event. If you want to affix it to your `this`, you need to use `.bind()` like so:

```
Incrementer.prototype.setOnClick = function() {
    document.getElementById("someDiv").onclick = this.increase.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try another way. You can avoid to use the property *prototype* and pass the html element to Incrementer at the declaration :

```
function myOnLoad() {
    var inc = new Incrementer(document.getElementById("someDiv"));
}

function Incrementer(newElement) {
    var value = 0;
    var element = newElement;

    this.increase = function(){
        element.innerHTML = ++value;    
    }

    element.onclick = this.increase; 
}
```