# Javascript OOP can't get property

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm trying to rewrite my code to OOP approach, but stuck in something.
There is an example :

```
   var counter = {
    column: {
    estimation: "tr td:nth-child(3)",
    worked:     "tr td:nth-child(4)",
    ratio:      "tr td:nth-child(5)",
    difference: "tr td:nth-child(6)"
    },

    columnLength : function display(){
        return $(this.column.estimation).length;
    },
```

Ok, it works! 
But if I will write almost the same, not in function though:

```
    var counter = {

    column: {
    estimation: "tr td:nth-child(3)",
    worked:     "tr td:nth-child(4)",
    ratio:      "tr td:nth-child(5)",
    difference: "tr td:nth-child(6)"
    },

    columnLength : $(this.column.estimation).length
    },
```

It doesn't, there is error :
Column isn't declared.

Why it must be in function? 
Thx in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword in Javascript act within an object literal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you're using `this` inside the jQuery selector `$(...)` the value of it is the global object `window` instead of the object `counter`. So, basically, you're trying to call the property column of the object window `window.column`, that it doesn't exist.

If you run the following code, you'll see what's the value of `this`:

```
var counter = {

 column: {
  estimation: "tr td:nth-child(3)",
  worked: "tr td:nth-child(4)",
  ratio: "tr td:nth-child(5)",
  difference: "tr td:nth-child(6)"
 },

 columnLength: console.log(this)
}
```

So, why is that happening?

Because when you're assigning an executed function to a parameter of a literal object, then that function is executed in the global context.

More info about the use of `this`: http://blog.kevinchisholm.com/javascript/context-object-literals/