# What is the usage of .bind()

Tags: javascript

I'm reading this code, and I can't get my head around the `.bind()` function.

There is a function, and in that function I see this statement

```
 this.layers.forEach(function(d){
           //some logic here
        }.bind(this));
```

Now, what is `.bind(this)` used for ie what does it mean, *and what would be different when it would not be added*?

The whole function is this:

```
get_data: function()
    {
        this.layers = [];

        //more logic

      this.layers.forEach(function(d){
           //some logic here
        }.bind(this));

        return this.layers;

    },
```

Reading the docs for .bind() didn't make it clear to me

Comment: I've read the article which is said to be duplicate, but I don't get that answer, not in relation to the code I am reading.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal/13441628#13441628

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/use-of-the-javascript-bind-method this post answers it very well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [**`this`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) context inside `Array#forEach` will be `window`, to have context of `your-own`(In your example, context of `get_data`), use `.bind` over `callback-function`

```js
var obj = {
  foo: function() {
    this.fName = 'NAME';
    [0, 1, 2, 3].forEach(function() {
      console.log('' + this);
      console.log('' + this.fName);
    });
  },
  bar: function() {
    this.fName = 'NAME';
    [0, 1, 2, 3].forEach(function() {
      console.log('' + this.fName);
    }.bind(this));
  }
}
obj.foo();
obj.bar();
```

Comment: did not know this: "this context inside Array#forEach will be window". So when I have a function, within that function 'this' points to the object the function is in. But in an array#foreach, this points to window?

Comment: @Michel, It is an impact of `jQuery` on us ;)

Comment: What has it got to do with jQuery?

Comment: Whow, this is weird to get my head around. And when I do `.bind(this)` and later on in the bar function I refer to `this.fName`, is that the same instance?

Comment: I took your code and played around with it, replacing `.bind(this)` to `.bind(otherobject)`, and then the `this` in the bar function is the `otherobject`. Coming from C# this is not easy to grasp

Comment: This sums up your misunderstanding: `within that function 'this' points to the object the function is in`. NO. Where `this` points to is a bit more complicated than that in javascript. See this answer to see how `this` works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal/13441628#13441628. `.bind()` a function that allows you to change where `this` points to.

Comment: When I do this `woo: function () {
  this.fName = 'NAME3';
  [0, 1, 2, 3].forEach(function () {
   console.log('' + this.fName);
  }.bind(myobj));
 }` and myobj is `var myobj = {
 fName : 'Michel'
}` it still prints 'Michel' and not 'NAME3'... Can't I set the value for `this.fName` in this case?

Comment: @Michel, How is your `myobj` structured ?

Comment: Understanding `this` in JavaScript is not a easy task!

Comment: @Rayon: it is `var myobj = { fName : 'Michel' }`

Comment: @slebetman : nice post, didn't know it has that many rules. Now I know, so I know what to check when looking for `this`

Comment: @Michel, In your example, Property `fName` is overwritten by `NAME3`, Have some different name for `key` and you will get it. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/nev17jmh/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115725/discussion-between-michel-and-rayon).

Comment: Thanks for the great advice (in stead of directly pointing to another answer)