# Cannot access a controller function inside $http.get method

Tags: angularjs

This is my controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [ 'ngMaterial' ]);
app.controller('searchController',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http) {
    this.selectedItemChange = function(item) {
        $http.get("url").then(function(response) {
            this.initializeProfiles();
        });
    }
    this.initializeProfiles = function() {}
}
```

But I am getting the error `TypeError: this.initializeProfiles is not a function`.

How do I access `initializeProfiles()` inside the .then of $http.get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a reference to the control from inside the callback, create one before you execute the call to the `http.get`.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [ 'ngMaterial' ]);
app.controller('searchController',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http) {
    this.selectedItemChange = function(item) {
    var me = this; // me = this
    $http.get("url")
        .then(function(response){
            me.initializeProfiles(); // me
    });
    }
    this.initializeProfiles = function() {}
}
```

---

See this excelent SO answer for a guide to how `this` is defined in javascript: [How does the "this" keyword in Javascript act within an object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal/13441628#13441628).

Comment: @pkyo - it has to do with `this`, the reference changes depending on the call stack and is not implicitly captured in a callback. There is a very good SO answer explaining all the details of `this`, give me a minute and I will find it.

Comment: @pkyo - found it, I updated my answer to include it at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', [ 'ngMaterial' ]);
  app.controller('searchController',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http) {
   var vm = this;
  vm.selectedItemChange = function(item) {
  $http.get("url")
    .then(function(response){
        vm.initializeProfiles();
   });
}
   vm.initializeProfiles = function() {}
}
```