# Equivalent of interfaces in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I have a function object in javascript called `BlinkyTextBox` Inside of that I have 2 `Shape` objects that act as scroll buttons. I need a something very simple to happen which is just  increment or decrement a variable called `scrollY`.

I tried it with an anonymous inner function, but the function couldn't recognize the member variables. Now I tried it with a member function, but it doesn't work with that either...

Here are both samples of what I am talking about.

```
function BlinkyTextBox(textdata, font, w, h)
{


    this.scrollY = -50;


    this.scrollBarYTop = new Button();

    this.scrollBarYTop.callFunction = this.scrollUp;

    this.scrollBarYBottom = new Button();
    this.scrollBarYBottom.callFunction = function()
    {
          this.scrollY -= 10;
    }

}
BlinkyTextBox.prototype.scrollUp = function()
{
    this.scrollY += 10;
}
```

Comment: `this` refers to something else inside the function  `.callFunction`, have a look at using `.call()` or `.apply()` to pass the scope into the function you're calling https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that once you assign a function to another object the `this` inside that function will refer to the new object instead of the object the function came from.

For example:

```
var a = {
    message : 'Hello!',
    say : function () { return this.message }
}

var b = {
    message : 'Goodbye'
}

b.say = a.say;

console.log(a.say()); // Hello!
console.log(b.say()); // Goodbye
```

Notice that we didn't do anything to the function `say()`. We just assigned it to `b` and it now print's the message from `b` instead of `a`.

Now, let's look at your code:

```
this.scrollBarYBottom.callFunction = function()
{
      this.scrollY -= 10; // refers to scrollBarYBottom.scrollY
                          // not BlinkyTextBox.scrollY
}
```

Same thing happens to the other method:

```
this.scrollBarYTop.callFunction = this.scrollUp;
// the this inside scrollUp will now refer to scrollBarYTop
```

Traditionally, to fix this you'd use an alias for `this`:

```
var myself = this;
this.scrollBarYBottom.callFunction = function()
{
      myself.scrollY -= 10;
}
```

But with ES5 you can use the `.bind()` method:

```
this.scrollBarYBottom.callFunction = (function()
{
      this.scrollY -= 10;
}).bind(this);
```

and:

```
this.scrollBarYTop.callFunction = this.scrollUp.bind(this);
```

Refer to this answer for a more detailed explanation of `this`: [How does the "this" keyword in Javascript act within an object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal/13441628#13441628)

Comment: When I do `this.scrollBarYTop.callFunction = this.scrollUp.bind(this);` I get an error that says `Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Comment: The other way with the `myself` works great! Thank you!