# Why is my bound this object being ignored?

Tags: javascript, node.js, this

I'm trying to call a method from a `require`d Node module with a specific `this` object. As far as I see, there are three ways to do this, with [`.bind(obj)(args)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), or with [`.call(obj, arg1, ...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), or with [`.apply(obj, aryArgs)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). I'm currently using `bind`, but I have tried all three with identical levels of not-success.

This is where I'm running the call:

```
var library = require("./library.js");

// ...

requestHandler.bind(library)(req);
```

`requestHandler` is a reference to the exported `status` function from this file:

```
exports.status = () => {
  console.log(this);
  this.render({text: "status ok"});
};

exports.paramSwitching = () => {
  this.render("rendered via param switching");
};

exports.json = () => {
  this.render({json: {this: 'renders', as: 'json'}});
};

exports.view = () => {
  this.render({view: true, locals: {text: 'hi'}});
};
```

I'd like this to work so that the `status` function is called with `library` as its `this` object, since that's where `render` is defined. However, the `console.log` statement is showing `this` as the evaluated contents of the file holding `status`, i.e.

```
{ status: [Function],
  paramSwitching: [Function],
  json: [Function],
  view: [Function] }
```

What's happening here, and how do I fix it? (Or, if I can't because Node is doing something weird, is there a workaround?)

Comment: Please include the code that defines `requestHandler`, given that it is not a reference to `.status` method in exports but rather the whole `exports` object

Comment: @Pineda: It's already included. Read the question carefully

Comment: As usual, whenever there is a misunderstanding of `this` I'll point readers to my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal/13441628?s=1|4.1585#13441628

Comment: @slebetman: Errr, it defines the binding of the object to library, but it could have been incorrectly referenced... It matters little given the fact that there are suitable answers now.

Comment: @Pineda I did check the reference, and it's what it's meant to be - referencing `status`, not the whole module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request handler is declared with arrow notation:

```
exports.status = () => {
  console.log(this);
  this.render({text: "status ok"});
};
```

By design the arrow notation captures `this` at the time the function is declared. It is almost as if you did this:

```
exports.status = (function(){
  console.log(this);
  this.render({text: "status ok"});
}).bind(this);
```

This means the `status()` function is already bound and cannot be rebound. The solution is to stop using arrow functions:

```
exports.status = function(){
  console.log(this);
  this.render({text: "status ok"});
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The arrow function itself already binds the `this` within the function body function to the `this` of the context it was defined in. So you cannot change the `this` with any of those methods.

If you need to change the `this` then you cannot use arrow functions.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out right after I posted this question. I've used arrow functions in the file containing `status`, which [do not create their own `this` scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) but use the enclosing context.

Calling `bind`, `call` or `apply` on these functions has no effect because `this` is already set to the function's enclosing context, which in this case is the eval'd file.

Switching the arrow functions out for regular functions (changing `() =>` to `function ()`) has fixed the issue.