# Why is it that the render() method of my component is the only one to have the correct value of 'this' by default?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

I was just wondering why render() has 'this' set to a 'correct' or intuitive value by default, but then any other methods I define on a component must have 'this' explicitly set?

For example:

```
class App extends React.Component {

    constructor (props) {
      super(props);
    }

    onFormSubmit (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(this);
    }

    render () {

      console.log(this);

      return (
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
            <input type="search"/>
            <button>Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      );
    }

  }

  ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById('app')
  );
```

The console output of the above is

```
App {props: Object, context: Object...}
null
```

Why is that? Is there any way to make it so that, by default, `this` will refer to the `App` in both cases? Or do I just need to keep writing `this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);` in the `constructor`?

Maybe it makes no sense to want this behaviour by default (I am very new to programming!) but if that is the case please do explain why :)

All the best

[edit] Also... why is it that `this` returns `null` when referenced inside the onFormSubmit function?

Comment: because other functions are used for transitioning data.. and that transition is asynchronous

Comment: The value of `this` depends on how a function is called. Not how it is defined. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal/13441628?s=1|4.2098#13441628

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case, have you tried `<form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit.bind(this)}>`? 
It should work without binding inside the constructor

---

For the EDIT:

Your `this` return null because you're just calling the method `.onFormSubmit()` defined in the Component `App` (returned by your first console.log line) without any context.

I invite you to check this ressources:

- To understand basics of .bind/.call/.apply methods

http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-apply-call-and-bind-methods-are-essential-for-javascript-professionals/

- A good tutorial for React, in this video he explains why you should always .bind() the context of this to prevent these issues

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_D1JGNidMr4&index=5&list=PLoYCgNOIyGABj2GQSlDRjgvXtqfDxKm5b

Comment: Manu, thank you for these links. That article on the bind(), call() and apply() methods was particularly helpful and there was also an article on that website about `this` which helped. What I think I learned is that `this` refers to the object which called the function in which `this` is referenced.

Comment: yes exactly, because when you're calling a method defined in an objectA, the only way to process it with a different context (from an objectB) is to bind or call the `this` context of objectB! 

Like `var a = { name: "Manu", showName: () => {return this.name}} `  ////

`var b = {name: "user3624937"}` ////

`a.showName.bind(b)` will return "user3624937"

Comment: Pleasure is mine! :)