# Callbacks usage with instanced objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, callback

I was facing a problem with callbacks in Javascript. I solved my problem using what I would call an ugly property of Javascript (so to say, something that would logically be forbiden and never work in other languages than Javascript). So my question: Is there an ELEGANT way, to do the same thing.

I will so begin with the beginning. My goal was to wrap, in some manner, the Web Audio API. In the architecture, I implemented a class, lets call it `AudioRessource`, which is destined to be an interface (abstraction) in some manner of the `AudioBuffer` object of the Web Audio API.

This class (`AudioRessource`) have a prototype member function that must simply take an url as argument to automatically load audio data, decode it, handle errors, etc and finally hold the resulting `AudioBuffer` object in a "pseudo-private" member:

```
function AudioRessource() 
{
   this._aBuffer = null; // future reference to `AudioBuffer` object
   this._loadStatus = 2;
};

AudioRessource.prototype.loadData = function(url) {
  /* deal here with async functions to 
     provides audio data loading automation */
}
```

The main problem here, is that this will be an object instance (of `AudioRessource`) which will create the callback functions, using only local references, and must be able to pass the final `AudioBuffer` object to itself.

To load the raw audio data, this is pretty simple, I use the XMLHttpRequest object, with an extra property set as member of the XMLHttpRequest object, like this:

```
AudioRessource.prototype.loadData = function(url) {
    let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.extraProperty = this; // reference to `AudioRessource` instance
    req.onload = function(){
       // retrive instance reference within the callback
       this.extraProperty._loadStatus = 0;
    }
    req.onerror = function(){ 
       // retrive instance reference within the callback
       this.extraProperty._loadStatus = -1;
    }
    req.open('GET', url, true);
    req.send(null);

    this._loadStatus = 1;
}
```

The big problem appear when we have to decode the coded raw audio data into PCM data, that is, an Web Audio API `AudioBuffer` object instance. Indeed, the Web Audio API provides only one function to achieve this, and this function is asynchronous, and takes a callback that simply recieve the resulting buffer as argument: how to "catch" this resulting buffer to assign it to the proper `AudioRessource` instance (the one who lauched the process) ? This work that way:

```
AudioCtx.decodeAudioData(rawData, 
                        function(result){ 
                          // do something with result },
                        function(error){
                          // do something with error });
```

My first naive approach, was to think like we were in C/C++ : I simply put an `AudioRessource` instance function "pointer" (reference) as callback, this way, the `AudioRessource` instance will directly recieve the buffer:

```
// where 'this' is an `AudioRessource` instance
AudioCtx.decodeAudioData(rawData, 
                        this._handleDecodeSuccess,
                        this._handleDecodeError);
```

However, this does not work, because in javascript, this is not a "function pointer" that is passed into the `decodeAudioData`, but if I well undstand, an literal expression, that is, the "ASCII content" of the function... So the 'this' reference is lost !

I spent some time to try understand how this kind of asynchronous function is attended to work, since to me, coming from C/C++, this is simply an heresy: The function does not take any extra argument, no way to pass any external reference... "What is that thing ?". Then I finaly decided to try the "Illogical Javascript logic" way... And I found the solution :

```
 // Create local variable which stores reference to 'this'
 let thisInstReference = this; 

 // Use the local variable to write our callback
 AudioCtx.decodeAudioData(rawData, 
                        function(resut){
                          thisInstReference._aBuffer = result;
                          thisInstReference._loadStatus = 0;
                        },
                        function(resut){
                          thisInstReference._loadStatus = -3;
                        });
```

To be honnest, to me, this is simply freaking. First of all, I even don't understand what realy happen: HOW a local variable (to a object instance's member function), that stores a reference to an object instance (this), can be used "as this" in a callback function ? I do not even understand how a language can allow this kind of thing. Secondly, to me, this not a "proper way" to code something: this code is simply illogical, dirty, this works but this appear as an ugly hack that takes advantage of Javascript misdesign.

So here is my question: How to achieve this, in a elegant way ?

Comment: Your understanding of the problem is wrong. The real issue is how `this` works in javascript. I will answer the direct solution to your problem below but please read the following answer to understand how `this` work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal/13441628#13441628

Comment: Also, if you are going to be working on modern javascript or C# or swift I suggest you take a second look at the "misdesign". It's being adopted by other languages. It's called a closure which is an abstraction over the concept of local and global variables.

Comment: Thanks god, I never going to work on C# or swift, and I now understand why I was naturally distrustful of these "proprietary$$" high-level languages... :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is simply due the the nature of how `this` works in javascript. The value of `this` is not bound at compile time nor at runtime but instead very late at call time.

In the following code:

```
AudioCtx.decodeAudioData(rawData, 
            this._handleDecodeSuccess,
            this._handleDecodeError);
```

.. the value of `this` inside `_handleDecodeSuccess` and `_handleDecodeError` is not determined at object creation time but instead at the time they are called. And it is the `decodeAudioData` method that will eventually call them when decoding is complete. This causes the value of `this` to become something else (depending on how the functions are called).

The modern solution is to statically bind `this` to the functions:

```
AudioCtx.decodeAudioData(rawData, 
            this._handleDecodeSuccess.bind(this),
            this._handleDecodeError.bind(this));
```

> Note: the .bind() method creates a new function that wraps your function with `this` permanently bound to the argument you pass to it.

The traditional solution is to capture `this` inside a closure like what you have done.

Comment: Thanks, so, I finally found the "proper way" despite appearances. Javascript have very interesting features, but sometimes it is very annoying how it naturally induces to writes confusing code. I will keep this .bind() method somewhere, maybe a better way for me produce "more readable" code to my tast.