# Trouble with passing "this"

Tags: javascript, object

Sorry for the poor title, i don't really know how to formulate my question.

The code below is a small part of a thing i'm doing to automate the generation of buttons paired with a click event for a game.
I'm tring to pass the `modal.load()` function (which takes an associative array as argument) as a string to the `"Look"` button. Well the function passing works (it is not in the code provided), BUT

As you can see, each properties of `actions[0].script` returns `undefined`, as if `this` is not passed..

Tell me if you need anything else to understand the code.

```js
actions = [{
    name: "Look",
    modal_color: 'salmon',
    modal_img: '',
    modal_title: 'This is a title',
    modal_text: 'This is text',
    script: `modal.load({'img': '${this.modal_img}', 'color': '${this.modal_color}', 'title': '${this.modal_color}', 'txt': '${this.modal_text}'});`,
  },
  {
    name: "Walk",
    script: "console.info('Other type of script')"
  }
]

console.log(actions[0].script)
```

EDIT : template strings for clarity

Comment: You're calling `this` before the object is even created, so it's referencing the wrong `this`.

Comment: But isn't `this` supposed to be actions[0] ?

Comment: No, an object literal has no `this`.

Comment: Related: [How does the “this” keyword in Javascript act within an object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal)

Comment: `this` would work after the object is created, like if you had a method on the object called `createScript` which then did `this.script = ... this.modal_img ... `. Probably overkill here.

Answer (score 3):

"this" works in a functional scope only, not in object scope

```js
actions = [{
name: "Look",
modal_color: 'salmon',
modal_img: '',
modal_title: 'This is a title',
modal_text: 'This is text',
script: function(){
    return `modal.load({'img': '${this.modal_img}', 'color': '${this.modal_color}', 'title': '${this.modal_color}', 'txt': '${this.modal_text}'});`;

}},
{
    name: "Walk",
    script: "console.info('Other type of script')"
}
]

console.log(actions[0].script())
```

Comment: I thought it would work, but when I click on the generated button, i get a console warning saying `SyntaxError: function statement requires a name`..

Comment: use `script: function f(){` i.e. give some name "f" to this function

Answer (score 2):

Would it work for you to iterate the array after the objects creation?

E.g.,

```js
 actions = [{
  name: "Look",
  modal_color: 'salmon',
  modal_img: '',
  modal_title: 'This is a title',
  modal_text: 'This is text'
   },
   {
  name: "Walk",
  script: "console.info('Other type of script')"
   }
 ];

 actions.forEach( (e) => { e.script = "modal.load({'img': '" + e.modal_img + "', 'color': '" + e.modal_color + "', 'title': '" + e.modal_color + "', 'txt': '" + e.modal_text + "'});" });

 console.log(actions[0].script);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, i finally decided to rework all my corresponding code to make things not as overcomplicated.