# Method execution javascript

Tags: javascript

Why this.name is not working here?how to fix that?

```js
var john = {
  name: 'John',
  greet: function(person) {
    alert("Hi " + person + ", my name is " + this.name);
  }
};
var fx = john.greet;
fx("Mark"); //Hi Mark, my name is
```

Comment: I'm no longer able to answer this because it was closed, but in my opinion, the best answer is to **use a `getter` that returns a function**. You don't need to apply contexts, or use global vars, etc. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/j6y9c0bx/

Answer (score 3):

`this` refers to the JavaScript `window` object in this case, because you are actually redefining the function name. Calling `john.greet ("Mark")` directly would work, because `this` would be referring to the object which the method is called on.

In your case, you can use the object name to refer to it's properties.

See this post for reference:
[How does the "this" keyword in Javascript act within an object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal)

Another possible solution is to change the context of the function itself, which can be done by using the [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) method. For details, refer to @Markus Stefanko's answer.

```js
var john = {
  name: 'John',
  greet: function(person) {
    alert("Hi " + person + ", my name is " + john.name);
  }
};
var fx = john.greet;
fx("Mark"); //Hi Mark, my name is
```

Comment: In this implementation I don't like the fact that you're relying on a global var name. Binding the context is a safer choice.

Comment: Good point! I've added an MDN link and a reference to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by binding the `this` context of `fx` like so :

```
var fx = john.greet.bind(john);
```

This way you're explicitly stating that fx will work with john as `this` context. Before that you're relying on the implementation to pick the context for you.

( For example your original code works when running as a snippet, but won't work in a browser context. )