# JavaScript var vs class

Tags: javascript, class, oop, syntax, var

This might sound like a weird question, considering variable and classes are completely different things, but I come from a Java background (Currently Associate degree level, 3rd year college student) and I've been reading up on javascript and watching videos.

A video about animation in js started with an intro to creating a `vector`  object. He defined a `vector` in its own file called `vector.js` and used it as the basis for particle motion in basic 2d animations.

Here is the code:

```
var vector = {
    _x: 1,
    _y: 0,

    create: function(x, y) {
        var obj = Object.create(this);
        obj.setX(x);
        obj.setY(y);
        return obj;
    },

    setX: function(value) {
        this._x = value;
    },
    getX: function() {
        return this._x;
    },
```

It continues with more getters and setters for angle, length, etc. Also defines methods for other vector operations like cross and dot product.

My questions are: 
-How is this different from using a class with methods? 
-Is this acceptable/standard code?
-Is the syntax `foo: function(args)` as a header the same as `function foo(args)`?
-Can you all point me to resources explaining the concept of having functions and parameters inside of seemingly a declared variale?

I have tried looking up information about, but I don't know if this syntax or usage has a name in js. I haven't seen anything like this in Java. I can't find any information.

Cheers.

Comment: _Can you all point me to resources explaining the concept_ - This is called Object Literal Notation or _initializer_ notation. Here is a reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Answer (score 2):

That's not a class. That's an object. In Java it's like an anonymous class. So Java does in fact have this exact same feature but with different syntax. In Java it would be something like this:

```
Object vector = new Object {
    private Integer x = 0;
    private Integer y = 0;

    // rest of code ... 
}
```

The one key difference is that unlike Java, javascript does not generate errors when you access properties of an object that doesn't exist. The above code would be a syntax error in Java because the Object class does not have members `x` and `y`. But javascript will silently add members that don't exist:

```
class Foo {
    constructor () {
        this.a = 1;
    }
}

var foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.a); // prints 1
console.log(foo.b); // prints "undefined"
foo.b = 2;          // NOT an error
console.log(foo.b); // prints 2
```

In javascript, the syntax `{}` is equivalent to `new Object()`. This is called the [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) syntax (technically it's specified as "object initializer"). This is in fact the origin of [JSON](https://www.json.org/) - it's based on javascript object and array syntax.

This behavior of objects in javascript means that it is often used in place of hashes/maps/hashmaps/associative arrays in other languages. Because it literally behaves like an associative array. So where in Java you have `Map` in javascript you'd use `{}`.

Comment: So it's only one instance of object? The video used multiple vectors at once.

Comment: It's a single instance, but it also has a method `create` that creates more objects that have it as their prototype, which means the objects created by `vector.create` also have access to all the methods on vector. It basically is a class, but there are lots of ways to make them in JavaScript.

Comment: @Josh If you're starting learning javascript I'd suggest first ignoring the prototype mechanism because it can get confusing quickly. Instead first learn how objects behave and the new `class` syntax and get comfortable with the language - then delve in to the gory details of prototype inheritance

Comment: @slebetman that makes sense. But can you explain the difference in method declarations?

Comment: @Josh Just read about function expressions. What you are seeing there is assigning a function to a property of an object. see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function

Comment: @Josh Also, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal/13441628?r=SearchResults&s=4|20.1327#13441628