# Why there are different outputs on calling same methods in this JavaScript example?

Tags: javascript

In below example, I tried calling `Animal` Class's methods *`speak()`* and *`eat()`* in 4 different ways, and they returned different results:

**Here is the example:**

```js
class Animal { 
  speak() {
    console.log(this);
    return this;
  }
  static eat() {
    console.log(this);
    return this;
  }
}

//scenario #1
let obj = new Animal();
obj.speak(); // Animal {}

//scenario #2
let speak = obj.speak;
speak(); // undefined

//scenario #3
Animal.eat() // class Animal

//scenario #4
let eat = Animal.eat;
eat(); // undefined
```

Can someone please explain why there are different results when we called the same methods (*`speak()`* and *`eat()`*) in these 4 scenarios?

**Output:**
[image: Output]

**Scenario #1:** *Prints: `{}`*

```
let obj = new Animal();
obj.speak(); // Prints: {}
```

**Scenario #2:** *Prints: `undefined`*

```
let speak = obj.speak;
speak(); // Prints: undefined
```

**Scenario #3:** *prints: Class definition of `Animal Class`*

```
Animal.eat() // prints: Class definition of Animal Class
```

**Scenario #4:** *Prints: `undefined`*

```
let eat = Animal.eat;
eat(); // Prints: undefined
```

Comment: Please feel free to suggest/edit a better title for this question (for the benefit of this SO community).

Comment: I keep an up to date answer explaining how `this` works in all situations. I will keep updating it as the standard evolves: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal/13441628#13441628

Comment: [Understand JavaScript `this` keyword](https://www.zeolearn.com/magazine/understanding-the-this-keyword-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One important aspect of Javascript is how `this` works.

When you execute

```
 x.foo()
```

what happens is that right before entering the code of `foo` the special value `this` is set to the object `x`. Writing for example:

```
 let f = x.foo;
 f();
```

is NOT the same, because here `this` will be set to the global object when entering the code of `foo`.