# JavaScript Define Property in Terms of Method

Tags: javascript, oop

Please note this question is not answered by
[Self-references in object literals / initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers)
as that question addresses defining properties in terms of other properites, not methods.

Also, [How does the "this" keyword in Javascript act within an object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal) is too high-level a decription of the subject for me to be able to solve my use case.

In Python, I can do this:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = self.get_id()

    def get_id(self):
        return 10

t = Test()
print(t.id)
```

Meaning an object property can be defined in terms of a method of the same object.

In JavaScript, it doesn't work:

```
var Test = {
  id : this.getId(),
  getId : function() {
    return 10;
  }
};
```

Gives `script.js:47 Uncaught TypeError: this.getId is not a function`

I've tried defining the `id` after the method definition but that didn't work.

How do I do this in JavaScript please?

Comment: How married are you to object literals?  A `class` would make this easier...

Comment: To be honest I thought object literals were how you did classes in JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answer (Evgeny Yudin) is simpler - but this is an alternative using classes that may add something to your understanding.

```
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.id = this.getId();
  }
  getId() {
    return 10;
  }
}

console.log((new Test()).id); //outputs 10
```

Comment: This is how I was going to answer it, since it exactly mirrors the Python code.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var Test = {
  get id() {
    return 10
  }
}

console.log(Test.id)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

or

```js
var Test = {
  get id () {
    return this.getId()
  },
  getId: function () {
    return 10
  }
}

console.log(Test.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `this` inside a method. There's no way to reference the current object in an object literal.

But you can refer to it after the object is created.

```
var Test = {
  getId : function() {
    return 10;
  }
};
Test.id = Test.getId()
```