# Javascript functions in associative array "is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

Recently I learned Javascript ES6 has classes so I tried them but my functions were always giving me errors saying they don't exist. So I made pseudo-classes using javascript associative arrays. **It was working absolutely fine** until I added some new methods.

Here is the error message I'm receiving:

```
EventListener.js:132 Uncaught TypeError: this.listen_for_tab_swap is not a function
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (EventListener.js:132)
at Object.alert_eventlistener_of_tabs (EventListener.js:41)
at Object.new_tab (EventListener.js:59)
alert_eventlistener_of_tabs @ EventListener.js:41
new_tab @ EventListener.js:59
xhr.onreadystatechange @ EventListener.js:94
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
(anonymous) @ EventListener.js:101
```

Here is the relevant code body:

```
const eventListener = {

     listen_for_tab_swap: function() {
         $(".footer button").on("click", function (event) {
             file_tabs.show_tab(event.target.innerText);
         });
     },

     listen_for_tabs_activation: function() {
         $("#AZ_content").on("tabs_loaded", function () {
             this.listen_for_tab_swap();
         });
     },

     listen: function() {
         $(function () {
             console.log("Yeah, I'm listening...");
             $(".menu").on("click", function (event) {
                 AZ_page_is_opened(event);
                 showTab(event, event.target.id.replace("Button", ""));
             });
         });
     }
 };
```

Please let me know if there is any additional information required to troubleshoot. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You are not using classes. You are just adding elements to an object that happen to be functions. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: I know. I called them "pseudo-classes". I'm not denying they have a real name.

Comment: You can't use `this` in a normal object. You have to add the functions to a prototype.

Comment: @LuketheGeek You can actually use `this` for a normal object, that's how objects work. The problem is `this` in that function is not what the OP expects it to be

Comment: @slebetman when I access the eventListener object through my developer console in chrome, it does say that eventListener.listen_for_tab_swap is undefined.

Comment: https://medium.com/better-programming/understanding-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-cb76d4c7c5e8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In js `this` is dynamic. It depends on how a function is called. I'm assuming you're using jQuery because it looks like jQuery syntax at a glance so for your specific case all you need to know is that in jQuery (and also in regular javascript) the value of `this` in an onclick event is the element that triggered the event:

```
{
  // ...

  listen_for_tabs_activation: function() {
     $("#AZ_content").on("tabs_loaded", function () {
         this.listen_for_tab_swap(); // this is AZ_content
     });
}
```

In the code above what you are doing is trying to call `$("#AZ_content")[0].listen_for_tab_swap()` and it is complaining that that HTML element does not have a method called `listen_for_tab_swap`

There are several ways to fix this. The simplest is probably do:

```
eventListener.listen_for_tab_swap();
```

You can also use arrow functions to bind `this`:

```
{
  // ...

  listen_for_tabs_activation: function() {
     $("#AZ_content").on("tabs_loaded",() => { // this fixes `this`
         this.listen_for_tab_swap();
     });
}
```

There are several more ways to solve this. Check out this answer to another related question for how `this` actually behaves: [How does the "this" keyword in Javascript act within an object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal/13441628#13441628)

Comment: I figured out the solution from reading only a bit of your answer. You've taught me a great deal. Thank you.