# Passing execution context in JavaScript from html elements

Tags: javascript

I am very new to JavaScript programming, and i am trying to do form validation using JavaScript.

While learning form validation i was reading about how to  disable submit button until all input fields are validated, i saw many techniques to do this, but, i am confused regarding the following code:

```
<body>
    <h3>Enter some values in the text to enable the button!</h3>
    <input type="text" id="txt" onkeyup="manage(this)" /> //focus here on "this" parameter
    <input type="submit" id="btSubmit" disabled />
</body>

<script>
    function manage(txt) {
        var bt = document.getElementById('btSubmit');
        if (txt.value != '') {
            bt.disabled = false;
        }
        else {
            bt.disabled = true;
        }
    }    
</script>
```

Here **this** is passed as an argument from an input element event listener in html. I tried passing something other than **this** from there, it didn't work only passing **this** works,

As far as i know **this** in JavaScript signifies current-execution-context, but since **this** is JavaScript keyword then how it is interpreted inside html?

JS FIDDLE LINK while passing 'this': https://jsfiddle.net/s0vnjpqb/

JS FIDDLE LINK while passing 'some': https://jsfiddle.net/s0vnjpqb/

**PS:** I am new to JavaScript, hence the question is easy, this might not match the standards of stack-overflow, but i tried researching in stack-overflow as well as on other platform i couldn't understand it.

Comment: There is no difference to how it is interpreted "in html". The `onkeyup` attribute value basically becomes the body of a `function` that is called as an event handler. Please show us how you tried passing other things.

Comment: instead of passing this from onkeyup, i tried passing "some_random_value" , that is replace "this" with "some_random_value" it didn't work.

Comment: Please show the code of that. And make sure the code is valid JS even after going through HTML escaping

Comment: The binding of `this` in javascript is a bit more dynamic and complicated compared to other languages. See my answer to this related question for how `this` behaves (note: I've tried and will continue trying to update the answer as javascript evolves): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal/13441628#13441628

Comment: @slebetman thanks very informative and useful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned correctly in the description that `this` in Javascript signifies the current execution context.

Similarly in html

`this` also represent the value of the ThisBinding of the current execution context and `this.value` indicates the value of the current execution context

e.g `txt.value` in your case.

Alternately what you can do is,

```html
<body>
    <h3>Enter some values in the text to enable the button!</h3>
    <input type="text" id="txt" onkeyup="manage()" /> //focus here on "this" parameter
    <input type="submit" id="btSubmit" disabled />
</body>

<script>
    function manage(txt) {
       var value = document.getElementById("txt").value;
        var bt = document.getElementById('btSubmit');
        if (value != '') {
            bt.disabled = false;
        }
        else {
            bt.disabled = true;
        }
    }    
    
    </script>
```

Comment: so do you mean "this" is also a reserved keyword in html? Since if i pass anything other that **this**(keyword), code dosen't work.

Comment: Good question Ayush.. :) I hope this answers your question, please have a look :) https://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html