# Problem getting a key value inside an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have a problem with this piece of code:

```
var Etudiants = {
"N13213316" : {
    "name" : "Touati Mohammed",
    "birthDate" : "05 June 2001",
    "age" : (Math.round((new Date().getTime() - new Date(this.Etudiants.N13213316[birthDate]).getTime()) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365.25)),
    "isStudent" : true,
    "departement" : {
            "2021" : "USMBA ENCG Fes",
            "2021" : "USMBA FLDM Fes"
    }
}
}
```

when i save it i get the following error code :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: birthDate is not defined

So basically i'm training to get the value "05 June 2001" to pass it as an argument to the Date function, but i can't do so, however i can access the value from the browser console, where i did make the mistake exactly and thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "this" keyword in Javascript act within an object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *birthDate* bit in the following expression:

```
this.Etudiants.N13213316[birthDate]
```

refers to the *birthDate* variable - which is not to be confused with the *"birthDate"* string. This variable is actually not defined here - hence your error message.

You should either change your code to refer to a string:

```
this.Etudiants.N13213316["birthDate"]
```

or leave your code as is, but declare the *birthDate* variable beforehand as pointing to the *"birthDate"* string:

```
var birthDate = "birthDate"
```

Note that you may run into other issues here though:

- If your code runs in strict mode, *this* will be undefined here - in which case *this.Etudiants* will trigger a *TypeError*.
- Even if your code runs in non-strict mode, at the time the *this.Etudiants* expression is evaluated here, it actually is undefined - the assignment to the *Etudiants* variable has not happened yet -, so *this.Etudiants.N13213316* will cause a TypeError.

Edit: to solve the later point, you would need to defer executing the *this.Etudiants.N13213316* expression until after the initial assignment to the *Etudiants* variable has actually happened. One simple solution would be as follows:

```
var Etudiants = {
"N13213316" : {
    "name" : "Touati Mohammed",
    "birthDate" : "05 June 2001",
    "isStudent" : true,
    "departement" : {
            "2021" : "USMBA ENCG Fes",
            "2021" : "USMBA FLDM Fes"
    }
}
}
Etudiants.N13213316.age = (Math.round((new Date().getTime() - new Date(Etudiants.N13213316["birthDate"]).getTime()) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365.25)),
```

Comment: Thanks for help, and yes indeed that what happened however i did what you suggested i got the same error message again.

Comment: Please make sure to confirm which variable or expression the error is now referring to.

Comment: Yes sure, The the undefined variable is N13213316 now

Comment: Ok, this is precisely the issue I was pointing to in the last part of my answer. I am adding a couple notes right now to point you in the right direction to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways of how you can access object properties in JavaScript:

1. With a dot:

   `object.property`
2. With square brackets:

   `object['property']`
3. With destructing:

   `const { property } = object`

So, basically, you mixed up two of these ways to access object property.

P.S. Do not access the field within the object literal as @roperzh mentioned.

Comment: No one of the methods you mentioned has worked, i tried them but always the same error